# Opening file in imported module

Tags: python, file, import

1. Suppose I have project structure like this:

```
    project \
        package1 \
            file1.py
        package2 \
            file2.py
```

2. In `package1.file1.py` I have something like

```
arguments_path = 'some_relative_path'
instance = SomeClass(arguments_path)
```

3. In `package2.file2.py` I want to import file from the first package:
   `from project.package1 import file1`. But accidentally I have `FileNotFoundError` since path `'some_relative_path'` in runtime  becomes invalid. It begins to look like `path_that_i_need\package2`
4. I tried using `absolutepath` and `realpath` but they don't resolve this as well. And I'm not able to hardcode `some_relative_path` variable since this code will be run on a great number of containers and services so it will be up to the machine it's run on.

I hope you will help me. Thank you anyways!

EDIT:

Traceback:

```
File "/home/lightningseas/mammography/service_inference/model/tests/test_inference.py", line 7, in <module>
    import service_inference.model.inference as inference
File "/home/lightningseas/mammography/service_inference/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    segmentation.load_state_dict(torch.load('./weights/segmentation.pth'))
File "/home/lightningseas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 419, in load
    f = open(f, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './weights/segmentation.pth'
```

Files structure:

```
service_inference \
      model \
         __init.py__
        other_files.py
        tests \
            test_inference.py
            other_tests.py
        weights \
            segmentation.pth
```

In `__init.py__`:

```
segmentation = Segmentation(1, 1)
segmentation = segmentation.cuda()
segmentation.load_state_dict(torch.load('./weights/segmentation.pth'))
```

In `test_inference.py` I import some files from model.
Using it not from `tests` directory works fine.

Comment: Can you clarify where exactly the file you're trying to open is, relative to the code files? It shouldn't matter which module uses the path, only what the interpreter's current working directory (CWD) is. If you're running the program from different places, (or running different scripts by name) you might end up with different working directories at different times, but that's an issue with how you run the program, not with the code opening the file.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the relevant info. Especially for the traceback, you can't format it properly in a comment. In the question you can.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks again! I edited my question

Comment: Do you mean that running the code from outside the test directory works fine? Which is your main file that you are trying to run? When you are running the python file in which there is an import from 'model', make sure you are running the code in the main directory - service_inference so that the import will work. If you run that code from test directory then it cant get the files from model.